# Unable to bind JSON data to KendoUI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

I am facing a certain issue while trying to bind the KendoUi Grid with the Json data from the controller. Things seem fine and my Json object contains data but still grid is not showing any thing:

And I am getting this error in chrome JavaScript console:

```
GET http://localhost:8084/Records?take=5&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=5 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In `View`:

```
<div id="grid">
</div>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    serverPaging: true,
                    pageSize: 5,
                    groupable: true,
                    selectable: "row",
                    transport: { read: { url: "Records", dataType: "json"} }
                },
                height: 400,
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                filterable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                        { field: "No", title: "No" },
                        { field: "Desc", title: "Description" },
                        { field: "priority", title: "Priority" },
                        { field: "decision", title: "Decision" }
                    ],
                dataBound: function () {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In `Controller`:

```
    public ActionResult GetRecords()
    {
       var obj = new User();
        var jsnRslt = obj.GetResult(Session["id"].ToString());
//return Json(jsnRslt);

        return Json(jsnRslt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Changed as suggested by Dismissile
    }
```

In `Model`:

```
public object GetResult(string usrId)
    {
…
….
…..            try
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (rcrds != null || rcrds.HasRows)
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                while (rcrds.Read())
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < rcrds.FieldCount; j++)
                    {
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(rcrds.GetName(j));
jsonWriter.WriteValue(rcrds.GetValue(j));
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return jsonWriter;
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Internal Server Error is saying that during the execution on the server something went wrong. Did you debug your application with breakpoints?

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but you are posting to your server but where is your action that will accept your params?

Comment: yes and till this line in `Controller` `return Json(jsnRslt);` everything is fine.. JSON object has the required data and all.

Comment: Do i need to specify params? .. currently the JSON is calling the action and no such exception is thrown on invalid params etc.

Comment: what is your controller returning as result? maybe internal server error? And why are you catching a exception without doing anything with it?

Comment: `return Json(jsnRslt);` from this I assume a serialized JSON object.. may be I am missing something as this is the first time i am working with JSON.

Comment: try to call `Json(jsnRslt)` in the imidiate window and see whats happening.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26871/discussion-between-jordy-van-eijk-and-maven)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this in your JSON call:

```
return Json(jsnRslt, JsonRequestBehavor.AllowGet);
```

It looks like you are doing a GET call, and by default GET is not allowed on a JSON call.

Comment: Done, but still no improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the transport attribute within dataSource, something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "EmployeeID",
                fields: {
                    EmployeeID: { editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                    EmployeeName: { validation: { required: true } }

                }
            }
        },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                type: "GET"

            },
            update: {
                url: "/Home/Update",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json'


            },
            destroy: {
                url: "/Home/Destroy",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json'

            },


            create: {
                url: "/Home/Create",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json'

            },


            pageSize: 1,





            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return kendo.stringify(options.models) ;
                }
            }

        }




    });





    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            sortable: true,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [

                { field: "EmployeeID", title: "Employee ID", width: 110 },
                { field: "EmployeeName", title: "Employee Name", width: 110 },

                { command: "destroy", title: "Delete", width: 90 }],
            editable: true,
            selectable: "multiple row",
            groupable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: true
        });
    });



</script>
```

The controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employee = new Employee().GetEmployeeList();

        return View(employee);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var obj = new Employee();


        return Json(obj.GetEmployeeList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Update(List<Employee> model)
    {
        var obj = new Employee();

        //return View();
        return Json(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(List<Employee> model)
    {
        var obj = new Employee();

        return Json(obj);
    }

    public ActionResult Destroy(Employee model)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Return a html view from index method to hold the grid &

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add a datasource request in your ActionMethod Parm

```
 public ActionResult GetResult([DatasourceRequest]request, string usrId)
 return Json(jsnRslt.ToDatasourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Every kendogrid needs this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 transport: { read: { url: "Records", dataType: "jsonp"} }
```

try with `jsonp` instead of `json`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an `ActionResult`, it should be a `JsonResult` instead.